# Ionic 2 RC0 can not open project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I've updated ionic 2 to the newest version RC0, released yesterday and now I can't open the new project. I'm getting the error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/username/workspace/project/www/index.html'
```

I've tried updating the npm, removing ionic 2 and installing it again but without positive results.

Can someone help me? I saw that many people have same problem...

Comment: When you say updating the npm, did you delete the entire directory and let it all reinstall?  That's what I had to do to fix this same problem.

Comment: Yes I did. I've started a new project from the beginning with the new CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem. If you ask me how, I don't literally know how. I've removed ionic and installed couple of times. Also cordova, npm and node and it just started to work...